# Why decision problem definition ignores Gödel incompleteness theorem?

Tags: computability, logic, decision-problem, incompleteness

The following question assume that the decision problem definition (syntactic) has been written (and could be changed if it isn't able) to catch a concept (meaning, semantic) which has both nice implications and some models. So please don't answer "the definition is the definition".

Let be any usual proof system, let $x$ be an object and let $P_{x}$ be a property. By Gödel incompleteness theorem, there are 3 cases :

1. $P_x$ is true and there is a proof for this.
2. $P_x$ is false and there is a proof for this.
3. $P_x$ is unprovable and there is neither a proof of trueness nor a proof of falseness.

But, regardless those 3 cases, a decision problem is defined by its set of positive instances (which hasn't even to match with 1.). Consequently, we must give truth value (positiveness/negativeness) to statements which don't have any in our proof system, I know that such a completion isn't inconsistent but it doesn't make much sense in my opinion.

Defining a decision problem constructivly, the decision problem would be just the target property, would make more sense. What could be the problems of such an approach ?

Comment: 1) Gödel's theorem does not apply to *all* proof systems. 2) How do we have interpret "nice implications" and "some models"? 3) Unprovable != no truth value. Decision problems are defined in a non-constructive fashion; we can define properties for which sometimes no proofs exist, c.f. halting problem (where proof means "the finite computation of an algorithm deciding the problem" here). 4) I have trouble understanding what you are asking. The "standard" definition of decision problems is rather clear. Can you give a formal definition of what you are proposing?

Comment: @Raphael 1) Ok, take ZFC or Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel 2) I give an example because it's not easy to formalize, any problem in $P \setminus P_{complete}$ can be solved on a TM in constant time : this is a nice implication (better than exponential time), but there is only 2 langages (2 models) in this complexity class.. 3) I know, I am asking why they are not defined in a constructing fashion. We can define unprovable property but is it meaningful to design a yes/no algorithm for the unprovable instances ? 4) I propose to define a decision problem as a property.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of "constructive". You are confusing it with "provable", as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is meanigful to **ask** for a construction if a yes/no algorithm for any property. But it may happen that there is no solution *because* the property in question is not decidable. According to your philosophy, a question is meaningless if it does not have an answer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I am deliberately confusing, it seems to me that in a constructive point of view you need a witness to argue that something is true, this witness is a proof. Exactly, a question is meaningless if it does not have an answer (is it even a question ?).

Comment: It has an answer! The answer is negative: the problem is *not* decidable.

Comment: Also, *witness* is not the same thing as proof. A witness can be infinite. It can be non-syntactic in nature, for instance topological. Consider for example sheaf-theoretic models of constructive mathematics. Or topological realizability.

Comment: "I am deliberately confusing" -- that is never constructive.

Comment: The decidability of the problem has an negative answer but not the problem itself. Ok, witness not the same thing as proof. I will edit my question when I will have more clear ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decision problem is a question of the form:

> *Does $x$ have property $P$?*

A solution to such a problem is a Turing machine $T$ such that:

1. For all $x$, $T(x)$ terminates.
2. If $x$ has property $P$ then $T(x)$ outputs `true`.
3. If $x$ does not have property $P$ then $T(x)$ outputs `false`.

Notice how formal systems play no role in the above. We are asking for a *machine* to corectly determine whether $P(x)$ is *true*. (The other possibiity is that $P(x)$ is *false*, and there is no third options, if you believe in excluded middle.) We did *not* ask for the machine to find a proof of $P(x)$! You should make sure to understand the difference between truth and provability.

There is an important class of decisions problems which have no solutions because of Gödel's incompleteness theorem. For instance, the decision problem

> *Does formula $\phi$ have a proof in Peano arithmetic?*

has no solution because there is no Turing machine that will correctly answer the question for all formulas $\phi$.

But in general decision problems are not directly linked to provability. For instance, the Halting Problem "does Turing machine $T$ stop on input $x$?" has nothing to do with any formal system. It is a question about machines.

Comment: "Formal systems play no role in the above" but when you said "x has the property" it's regarding a proof system or some axiomatic theory. I don't believe in the excluded middle, I am asking for a constructive decision problem definition. I edit my question.

Comment: I most definitely did not ask for a proof when I said "$x$ has property $P$"!  It is essential that you understand the difference between "is true" and "has a proof". A statement which has a proof is true, but not every true statement has a proof. **Proofs are a way of verifying that something is true** and **they are not the same thing as truth**. Even if you do not believe in excluded middle, the definition of decision problems still stands and it has nothing to do with provability.